# Removing duplicates from a linked list

Tags: java, linked-list

I have the following code but I don't understand where `head` is modified:

```
static void removeDuplicates(Node head) {
    HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
    Node previous = null;

    while (head != null) {
        if (set.contains(head.data)) {
            previous.next = head.next;
        } else {
            set.add(head.data);
            previous = head;
        }
        head = head.next;
    }
}
```

What confuses me is that `head` is set to `null` every time the function ends. Why is the method still correct?

Comment: Where do you see `head` being set to null? I see it set to `head.next`.

Comment: the loop runs as long as `while (head != null)`. So when the loop ends, the local variable `head` is inevitably `null`.

Comment: Ah, I see. But it's just a local variable, what's wrong with that?

Comment: I don't see a problem with it either, the original `head` is not modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`head` is a variable (by way of being a local parameter). Given that it is a variable of a non-primitive type, the thing it holds is *a reference*. It's like a treasure map. Not like treasure. You can use it to get to treasure, but it is not, itself, treasure.

Java is strictly pass-by-value, i.e., everything **is a copy**. Whatever code called `removeDuplicates` had a treasure map, and made a copy of this map, and handed that copy to the `removeDuplicates` method.

`head = head.next` is java-ese for:

- (`head.next` - the `.` specifically): Dot is 'dereference': Take the `head` treasuremap, follow it to the X, dig down, and open the treasure. Inside, find a little tab named 'next'. On it, you will find a treasure map (that's a treasure map, in a treasure chest).
- Now the `head = ...` part: Now take the `head` treasure map and **erase what is there**. Then copy over the `next` map from the chest. When you're done, put the `next` map back in the chest, close it up, and cover it back up.

At the end of the method, `head`, which is just a local treasure map, just poofs out of existence immediately, as do all local variables.

Yeah, on the last run, `head = head.next` means that `head` is blank (`null`) - the last treasure chest you open does have a piece of paper named `next` that can contain a treasure map, but it is blank (`null`), and you copy this over, thus, `head` itself will be blank.

This is irrelevant. `head` poofs out of existence entirely (the treasure map, not the treasure it leads to), given that it is a local variable and the method that created it ends, and this has absolutely no effect whatsoever on the caller, because its treasure map wasn't changed or destroyed at all - the copy it made was, so this doesn't matter.

Make a very slight change and this becomes a different story: If instead of `head` being a local var, it was a field (so, replace `removeDuplicates(Node head)` with `removeDuplicates()`, and let's posit that there is a field `private Node head;` in whatever class this method is in), then `head = head.next` is wiping out the treasure map that is **the field itself** which obviously survives the method's execution, and will be visible by other code. **Then** your idea that 'hey wait a second this destroys `head`!' carries water.